# UICollectionView Built in IB not displaying cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've created a simple app and dragged a `UICollectionView` onto it. There is one cell, I've given it an ID of cell and added a label to it. I've also changed the background color of the `collectionview` and the cell.
When I run the app in the simulator the `collectionview` is there but the cell is not.
I have no Idea what i'm doing wrong an i'm starting to get really pissed off.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, APExpandingTextViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1;

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    return cell;

}
```

Nothing ever shows up.

screen shot of the IB
[image: IB Layout of UICollectionView]

Comment: @user1089677 have u checked datasource and delegate  of collection view in IB ?

Comment: wow thanks!  I was looking for answers for too long and it ended up bing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check datasource and delegate of collection view are connected or not in storyboard.**
[image]